# NuGet not copying necessary binaries to output path

Tags: c#, nuget, gdal

I am installing GDAL 1.11 via NuGet on Visual Studio 2015 and it does not copy the necessary folder "gdal" that contains all DLL's for runtime.

Does anyone know a workaround, or how to fix this?

Comment: Looking at the package in NuGet Package Explorer I only see two `GdalConfiguration.??.pp` files in the `content` folder and otherwise just some assemblies which should be added as references, but no `gdal` folder. Are you sure it should be included in the package?

Comment: NuGet has upgraded quickly, but the package you use was authored in 2015. You really should contact its developers to make sure it can still work.

Comment: @RayKoopa yes a gdal/ folder is necessary to be present in the output bin/ folder for DLL loading

Comment: @LexLi I will contact them.

Comment: @manatttta They probably expect you to add that folder manually to your solution, as it's not directly provided by them.

Comment: @RayKoopa it is provided by them, because it is downloaded to the sources folder. It is just not puclished alongside my web app